# Match multiple columns of Excel and highlight if the value is a complete or partial match upto certain characters

Tags: excel, vba, match, multiple-columns

I have two Excel files Source File and Working File. Source file has name of organisations which are blacklisted. The Working File has 11 columns in which the name of organisations are mentioned. I need to complete match or Partial Match upto certain characters in the Working File. If the Working File has complete or partial match those values to be highlighted with Red Background in the Working File. I tried some VBA codes but not having a working solution. I am just a beginner need help on this please.

Answer (score 0):

Load the entries of the Source File in an array, go to the Working file and check Row by Row for each column, if the cell content is listed in the array. If yes, mark it red.

Comment: Yes @Tdi Ger, that's correct. Could you please help me with a code for the same?

Comment: This is not the place to learn the basics of VBA.
Here you might get some hints how to solve specific problems in an existing module.
Since I do not know how your sheets are defined, where I can find which column, which RowRange has to be dealt it's nearly impossible to provide you a source code which runs in your environment.

Comment: I understand that this is not a platform to learn basics. However, need some urgent help which is why thought to post here.
The Source File details will be in Column A and the file in which I need to match the details will be in Column Q to Column AA. The number of rows will vary. Kindly help me if you can with code. The task is bit urgent.